# WordPress images reloaded when refreshing a page (I don't want it to)

Tags: wordpress

When I refresh the page, it reloads the images which is something I don't want

I am working on two WordPress blogs, on two different servers. http://www.i-phony.com/ & http://www.dz-ahbeb.com.
They have the same exact template. But the is a problem is only with the first website. even though the settings are the same.

I tried disabling plugins and the problem was still there.

What do you suggest?

Thanks everyone

Update:

I added this to the .htacess file, and it made the blog load much faster, which means it saves cache, but I still can see the images "flash" they disappear before they appear again.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this is performance related. It's not that the logo isn't loading quick enough, it's that it's being requested too late.

If you look at a waterfall report for the [i-phony site](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130929_CA_7W/1/details/) you'll see that the logo and the rest of the images are loading quite late. It's loading the logo file (request 33) way after it's loading a bunch of blocking javascript.

The other site is loading the logo and images much earlier (see waterfall [here](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130929_R1_98/1/details/) request 10) and loading the javascript much later to prevent it blocking the page render.

There are a few things you can do to speed up the loading of the images. Firstly I suggest you load as much of the javascript in the footer as you can and combine & minify as many css and javascript files as you can to lower the transfer amount and total requests.

You can use a plugin like W3 Total Cache to combine+minify+defer the js to footer without needing to make any changes to the underlying code.

Comment: W3 Total Cache was already installed.. Probably will try to arrange priority of which files should load first.

Comment: Definitely try rearranging, especially the javascript. It should be fine to defer most of it to the footer and W3 Total Cache allows you to load the files asynchronously which way help. Best of luck getting it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Are they on the same server? It is possible that browser.cache header is different in different environments.

There are browser cache directives that can be sent to tell the client's browser how long to keep page objects like images, media content, page html, stylesheets, javascripts, etc in the local client browser cache before trying to refresh. These directives are enabled through DSO modules (apache web server), server configuration and .htaccess file entries.

Example apache directive

```
#Set caching on image files for 11 months
<filesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|png)$">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 11 month"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Actually no, they're not in the same server. The one with the problem is on a VPS, so it's more customizable. Don't you have any suggestion on what i should do?

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi see my comment.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't think it's about caching the files. The problem seems to be different